# programming how a variable is displayed on an email C# web form

Tags: c#, email, webforms

HI I am new to programming and am using visual studio to create a web application.
What I would like to know is how can I display the result of a variable as red text in an email. Here is what I have :

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Var1 = Label3.Text;
        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
        {
            Label10.Visible = true;
            TextBox1.Visible = true;
            Var1 = TextBox1.Text;
```

----- This text must display as red in the email ----------
            }

```
        else
        {
            Label10.Visible = false;
            TextBox1.Visible = false;
            Var1 = Label3.Text;
        }

    }

m.Body = @"Hi "+ "<br/><br/>" +
                    "" + "Please note the current Flash Programming settings are incorrect. The Settings should be: " + "<br/>" +
                    "" + "Product : " + DropDownList1.Text + " Program Name : "+ Label3.Text +" CRC : "+ Label5.Text +" Daughter Card : "+ Label7.Text +" Etching : "+ Label9.Text + "<br/>" +
                    "" + "Currently the settings are :" + "<br/>" +
                    "" + "Product :" + DropDownList1.Text+ " Program Name : "+  Var1  + " CRC : " + Var2 + " Daughter Card : " + Var3 + " Etching : " + Var4 + "<br/><br/>" +
                    "" + "Regards" + "<br/>" +
                    "" + "QC Team";
                m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                sptmClient.Send(m);
```

Comment: Since your mail is `IsBodyHtml == true`, simply wrap a html tag around it, e.g. `<span style="color:red;">`

Comment: HTML `" Program Name : <span style='color:red;'>"+  Var1  + "</span> .....` - Sending an email in SelectedIndexChanged may not be the best place to do it - you could end up sending several.

Comment: See https://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/667848-changing-text-color-string-email-message

Comment: Will that make only a certain value red or the variable red irrespective of value ?

Comment: It will color the variable regardless of value. You have to do the following in your `else` block: `Var1 = "<span style='color:red;'>" + Label3.text + "</span>";` or new syntax (C#6) `Var1 = $"<span style='color:red'>{Label3.Text}<span>"`

Comment: The red span is fixed within the constant HTML string so any `var1` will naturally be red. `Var1 = "<span ..." + Label3.Text + "</span>";` would be selective.

Comment: Ok what I am doing is this I am creating an application that our quality team uses and it automatically emails management when settings are incorrect so I display the correct settings and display incorrect settings as well so I want my mail to highlight the incorrect settings or make them red so currently my variable can be right or wrong if my variable is wrong I want it to be red on the mail

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            String body = @"Hi " + "<br/><br/>" +
                "" + "Please note the current Flash Programming settings are incorrect. The Settings should be: " + "<br/>" +
                "" + "Product : " + DropDownList1.Text + " Program Name : " + Label3.Text + " CRC : " + Label5.Text + " Daughter Card : " + Label7.Text + " Etching : " + Label9.Text + "<br/>" +
                "" + "Currently the settings are :" + "<br/>" +
                "" + "Product : " + DropDownList1.Text + " Program Name : ";

            if (Var1 == Label3.Text)
            {
                body = body + Var1 + " CRC : ";
            }
            else 
            {
                body += "<span style='color:red;'>" + Var1 + "</span>" + " CRC : ";
            }

            if (Var2 == Label5.Text)
            {
                body = body + Var2 + " Daughter Card : ";
            }
            else
            {
                body += "<span style='color:red;'>" + Var2 + "</span>" + " Daughter Card : ";
            }

            if (Var3 == Label7.Text)
            {
                body = body + Var3 + " Etching : ";
            }
            else
            {
                body += "<span style='color:red;'>" + Var3 + "</span>"  + " Etching : ";
            }

            if (Var4 == Label9.Text)
            {
                body = body + Var4 + "<br/><br/>" + "" + "Regards" + "<br/>" + "" + "QC Team"; ;
            }
            else
            {
                body += "<span style='color:red;'>" + Var4 + "</span>" + "<br/><br/>" + "" + "Regards" + "<br/>" + "" + "QC Team"; 
            }

            SmtpClient sptmClient = new SmtpClient("ra.uec.co.za");
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            m.To.Add(new MailAddress("Rajiv.Sahadeo@uec.co.za"));
            m.From = new MailAddress("noreply@uec.co.za");
            m.Subject = "Incorrect Flash Programming Settings in Red";
            m.Body = body; 
            m.IsBodyHtml = true;
            sptmClient.Send(m);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("NotificAation sent to Management");
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery,false);
        }
        else
        {
```

> This fixed the issue